# Why do I get a Runtime Error in Google Kickstart's Online Grader but not in my own IDE?

Tags: python, runtime-error

I was doing the Google Kickstart 2020 Round C and my code for the 'Perfect Subarray' question kept giving me a runtime error on the online grader.

I do realise that my code isn't efficient (i've used a brute force technique of checking every subarray); however, it does work properly on 'test set 1' when I run it locally.

Here is my code:

```
from math import sqrt
testCases = int(input())
outputLines = []

def isPerfect(left,right):
    summed = sum(arrayOfIntNumbers[left:right+1])
    squareRoot = sqrt(summed)
    intSquareRoot = int(squareRoot)

    if(squareRoot == intSquareRoot):
        return True
    else:
        return False

for test in range(testCases):

    numOfnumbers = int(input())
    stringOfnumbers =  input()

    arrayOfStringNumbers = stringOfnumbers.split()
    arrayOfIntNumbers = [int(stringNumber) for stringNumber in arrayOfStringNumbers]

    # checks with everything ahead of it
    perfectSumsCount = 0
    for i, number in enumerate(arrayOfIntNumbers[0:len(arrayOfIntNumbers)-1]): # go thru all but the last one
        currentPosition = i + 1
        # disallow for last item. done above
        while(currentPosition < len(arrayOfIntNumbers)): # goes tille nd
            # checker function.  left bound right bound
            if (isPerfect(i,currentPosition) ==  True):
                perfectSumsCount += 1
                #print(str(i+1) + " " + str(currentPosition+1))

            currentPosition += 1

    for numero in arrayOfIntNumbers:
        squareRoot = sqrt(numero)
        intSquareRoot = int(squareRoot)

        if(squareRoot == intSquareRoot):
            perfectSumsCount += 1


    outputLines.append("Case #" + str(test + 1) + ": " + str(perfectSumsCount))

for output in outputLines:
    print(output)
```

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong.

Here is the question: https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/kickstart/round/000000000019ff43/00000000003381cb

Answer (score 0):

I have found the errors in my code (with the help of someone on reddit).

The problem was that the sqrt() method gives an error when a negative nummber is passed in. I kept getting an RE on the online grader because one of the subarrays in one of the testCases had a negative sum.

Another optimization fix is that my code my is O(n^3) when it can be O(n^2) quite easily. Instead of making every single subarray, I can keep a sum counter and add elements to it, and then check if the sum is a perfect square.